# Should all text be placed in paragraphs tags?

Tags: html, css

If I have small amounts of text I need to add to a webpage, should they always be in `<p>` tags? Or is it ok to just have them in a div occasionaly?

Comment: Absolutely OK to have them even outside all elements. What rules are you validating against?

Comment: If you want your content to be marked up semantically, use the proper HTML tags for the job. It matters to search engines, screen readers, and other "needy" users.

Comment: If `<p>` tags are bad practice the whole web is broken... Do you mean for a specific usage? The question mentions no special usage.

Comment: David, please remove your comment – before I have to make a feature request to SO for the possibility of downvoting comments …

Comment: Hey David, you're a few days early if that was an April Fools joke ;)

Comment: Previously asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907313/is-the-div-tag-ever-an-undesirable-alternative-to-the-p-tag

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<div>`'s should be used for layout and positioning purposes, not for storing text.

Using `<p>` tags is semantically correct in this case - similarly, semantically correct pages tend to be ranked higher in search engines for various reasons (such as how effectively crawlers parse your website etc.).

Answer (score 2):

It would be a better choice to use "p" tag for sorting text.You can put "p" tag inside a "div" tag if you want to apply particular styling to a layout.If you want to keep your text's formatting you can use "pre" tag.